# Spring: autowired Configuration is null when using @Validated annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation

Usually I use a class to load all configurations from a yml and make them available throughout my application by autowiring the configuration. This works just fine until I try to validate the configuration by adding the @Validated annotation.

If the validation fails, the application fails to start and I get a message including the incorrectly set property.
If the validation succeeds, my autowired configuration is null, even though I can see by debugging, that the correct values are read and set from the yml file.

```java
//full configuration class
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
@Validated
public class ConfigurationStore {

    @Valid
    public MyConfiguration myConfiguration = new MyConfiguration();

    public ConfigurationStore setMyConfiguration(MyConfiguration myConfiguration) {
        this.myConfiguration = myConfiguration;
        return this;
    }

    public static class MyConfiguration {

        @NotBlank
        public String configuredString;

        public void setConfiguredString(String configuredString) {
            this.configuredString = configuredString;
        }
    }

}
```

```java
//class where autowired configuration is always null
import {package}.ConfigurationStore;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import(ConfigurationStore.class)
public class MyConfig {

    private ConfigurationStore configurationStore;

    @Autowired
    public MyConfig(ConfigurationStore configurationStore) {
        this.configurationStore = configurationStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public String returnIt() {
        return configurationStore.myConfiguration.configuredString;
    }
}
```

Removing @Validated removes the validation functionality. Keeping it, results in the autowired configuration being null.
What I expect is the configuration AND the validation to work simultatiously.

Comment: Make the field `myConfiguration` a private field and add a public getter. Use that instead of direct field access. For the validation to work a proxy is being created, you are now accessing the field on t he proxy which will always have `null`. Using a getter will pass through the proxy to the actual instance containing the values.

Comment: try removing '@'validated annotaion from class level, '@'valid at varibale level should work fine.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. The getter really works. I did not know about the proxy creation. Removing the validated annotation removes the validation functionality, so I can't do that, Praveen